# How to fill dynamic in-memory array

Tags: solidity, remix, storage, arrays, memory

For some reason solidity doesn't allow to push values into memory array

> Member "push" is not available in bytes32[] memory outside of
>   storage.

Here is sample contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract Foo {
    function getRange(uint n) public pure returns(uint[]) {
        uint[] memory result;
        for (uint i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (someCondition(i))
               result.push(i);
        return result;
    }
}
```

I could allocate maximum possible array of size `n` and then shrink it, but it may hurt performance (`n` could be in order of magnitude of `100000` while final length of result is `0..100`). For example, `someCondition` could be `isPrime`. In this case we have large N (which makes impossible to preallocate an array) and small list of resulting prime numbers.

How could it be done?

---

I ended up with preallicating array of size `n` and then shrinking it once I know it's final length:

```
function getRange(uint n) public pure returns(uint[]) {
    uint tookCount = 0;
    uint[] memory result = new uint[](n);
    for (uint i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (someCondition(i)) {
            result.push(i);
            tookCount++;
        }

    uint[] memory trimmedResult = new uint[](tookCount);
    for (uint j = 0; j < trimmedResult.length; j++) {
        trimmedResult[j] = result[j];
    }
    return trimmedResult;
}
```

Comment: push isn't available for memroy array read the documentation http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/types.html. for your new edit you have to omit the pure keyword and either you add elements using an array indice or by using a storage array

Comment: @BadrBellaj I cannot use a storage because this function should not affect contract.

Comment: if you know the array size create a memory array with length n :         uint[] memory result = new uint[](n);

Comment: @BadrBellaj no, I don't. I tried to enhance my question to make it clearer, thank you.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Dynamic arrays are only available in storage, not in memory. In your case, the size of the `result` array is known upfront (`n`). So, you can just declare an array with length of `n`. Then you can fill it up using `i`, which goes from `0` to `n - 1`

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract Foo {
    function getRange(uint n) public pure returns(uint[]) {
        uint[] memory result = new uint[](n);
        for (uint i = 0; i < n; i++)
            result[i] = i;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it was a bad example. Please, see edit.

Comment: still working for 0.8.11 lol

Answer (score 2):

**as i know**

push is only for storage arrays not memory arrays

from the doc :

> push: Dynamic storage arrays and bytes (not string) have a member
>   function called push that can be used to append an element at the end
>   of the array. The function returns the new length.

try

```
result[j]=keccak256(id);//declare j
```

Comment: Isn't it out of bounds access? Or I should implement my own dynamic array resize?

Comment: no for array resizing here's the doc http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#allocating-memory-arrays

Comment: Okay. So I have manually implement list? Allocate some array. Fill it. When I have to push yet another item I should allocate new array, copy all items from the old one, replace old array with new one and finally add an item there? And when I'm done I should allocate yet another array a final result, and copy all items in it? I supposed there is some library (if language isn't support if out of the box). Please see updated question if I was unclear in comment.

Answer (score -1):

Since you have a condition in the iteration I will add this key in Henk's answer:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract Foo {
    function getRange(uint n) public pure returns(unit[] memory result) {
        uint j = 0; 
        for (uint i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (someCondition(i))
                result[j] = i;
                j++;
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use storage instead of memory

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract Foo {
    function getRange(uint n) public view returns(uint[]) {
        uint[] storage result;
        for (uint i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (i> 1)
               result.push(i);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code has a bug if there's a non empty `uint[]` in the first slot.